# Codeigniter black diamond characters

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding

This is more of a curiosity than actual problem as there is an easy and propably more preferable workaround.  When using Codeigniters form validation and when displaying error message the CI user guide gives two ways to set one's own validation messages: through `set_message-method` and editing the language file which is located in the system folder.

However when editing the language file to contain error messages in my native language (which contains special character liks 'Ä' and 'Ö') the special characters are replaced with a black diamond.  When using the `set_message-method` from `form_validation` it works without a problem and the characters are encoded with UTF-8 properly.

I am wondering where lies the problem when using the file instead of the method and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the file is not saved by your editor as UTF-8. Make sure that it is.